# how can i find the path of the image in VsC?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have add some images in the this file `assets/backgrounds` , so when i want to add them to some styledDiv , i use   `background-image: url(assets/backgrounds/${randomImage}.jpg);` but the image is not available in url [image]

so i try to import the image and try like this
`import imag from 'assets/backgrounds/3.jpg';` and the `console.log(imag)` the result is this `/static/media/3.c49045ad.jpg` and what is this mean , what im doing wrong ?